# Using methods of classes in android programming

Tags: java, android

Hi everyone I am a beginner in android, please help.
I have DBAdapter class which has different methods to manipulate my db.
I want to call the method i.e. insert when button is clicked. However it only works outside of listener (View.OnClickListener).

```
    package com.dbclass;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class DBActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(btn1Listener);


        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);        
        db.open();  

        long id;
         // this needs to go to setOnclick method
        id = db.insertTitle(
                "0470285818",
                "Alanel",
                "Wrox");        

        Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {          
                DisplayTitle(c);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();
    }

    public void DisplayTitle(Cursor c)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, 
                "id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
                "ISBN: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                "TITLE: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
                "PUBLISHER:  " + c.getString(3),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
    }
    private View.OnClickListener btn1Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                 // db.insertTitle("0470285818", "Alanel", "Wrox");  

        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of `db` is only within your `onCreate()` method.  You may want to make it a public member of your `Class`.

Answer (score 2):

Make your `db` variable a field of the `DBActivity`. You probably don't want to do db operations on the UI thread though.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are closing `db` at the end of your `onCreate()` method.  You should make sure to `open()` and `close()` it again in your `onClick()`.  You should also probably do the actual work in a background thread that you start from you `onClick()` method.